# How to read all the records of mnesia database in erlang?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I ma new in erlang and I need to do some operations for all records I get from mnesia database.

```
Result = mnesia:dirty_read(mydatabase, {key1, key2}),
        case Result of 
            [] ->
                ?DEBUG("No such record found", []);
            [#mydatabase{key3 = Key3}] ->
                %% some operations
        end
```

How can I add a loop to my code that execute some operations for all records?

I am not even sure if the code above does it or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`mnesia:foldl/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#foldl-3) for that. It iterates over all records in a table, passing along an "accumulator" value.

It doesn't have an explicit "dirty" counterpart, so if you want to run it as a dirty operation you need to use `mnesia:activity/2`.  (Or you could just use it inside a call to [`mnesia:transaction`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#transaction-2).)

In this example, I don't actually do anything with the "accumulator", leaving as `ignored_acc` throughout.

```
mnesia:activity(sync_dirty,
  fun() ->
      mnesia:foldl(
          fun(#mydatabase{}, Acc) ->
              %% do something with the record here
              Acc
          end,
          ignored_acc,
          my_table)
  end)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try all_keys(Tab)

> all_keys(Tab) -> KeyList | transaction abort
>
> This function returns a list of all keys in the table named Tab. The
>   semantics of this function is context sensitive. See mnesia:activity/4
>   for more information. In transaction context it acquires a read lock
>   on the entire table.