# Using Erlang mnesia:read/2 Returns Nothing

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, mnesia

I have a ram_copies mnesia set up and I can insert the records, and I can print the them using the following code located here: [How to read all the records of mnesia database in erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849496/how-to-read-all-the-records-of-mnesia-database-in-erlang)

Start Record:

```
-record(someRecord, {a=null, b=null}).
```

Table:

```
mnesia:create_table(someRecord,
    [{attributes, record_info(fields, someRecord)},
      {index, [#someRecord.b]},
      {ram_copies, Nodes},
      {type, set}]),
```

Inserting:

```
i(rA, rB) ->
  F = fun() -> mnesia:write(#someRecord{a=rA, b=rB}) end,
  mnesia:transaction(F).
```

Reading:

```
r(rB) ->
  F = fun() -> mnesia:read({someRecord, rB}) end,
  mnesia:transaction(F).
```

This returns {atomic, Result} and Result is empty.

Wondering what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Update:  It turns out that if I use the record "a" as they key it works.  But why?  I have it set to record "b" for key.

Comment: Does this work: `mnesia:index_read(someRecord, B, #someRecord.b)`?

Comment: @Dogbert This works.  However, why does create_table have a key value that is not used then " {index, [#someRecord.b]}," (unless I am using it wrong).  The read/2 will work for me if I replace rB with "a".  Seems like the key is the first element, is this hardcoded?  Also, what is the impact of using index_read vs read?

Comment: I've posted an answer for all your questions except the last one. I am not sure about the impact. I believe it should be as fast as searching the first field but there will be an overhead in other operations because of the extra index `mnesia` needs to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{index, List}` option specifies which of the elements of the tuple `mnesia` should index. It does not change the behavior of `mnesia:read` to search those fields. The first field of the record is treated as the primary key and indexed automatically and is the one `mnesia:read` searches. To make a query against any other element, you need to use `mnesia:index_read` and specify the index of the element:

```
mnesia:index_read(someRecord, B, #someRecord.b)
```

Also note that since the type your table is `set`, and the first field of the record is the primary key, you will not be able to store more than one record with the same value of `a`. If you want `b` to be the primary key and the key on which the `set` detects duplicates, you'll have to reorder the fields of the record and move `b` to before `a`. If you do that, you don't need to specify any `index` option and you'll also be able to use `mnesia:read` instead of `mnesia:index_read`. This should be more efficient as well since `mnesia` won't have to maintain an extra index.

Comment: I am a bit confused on what "Index" refers too here and what would be the impact on choosing say a string as an index vs list vs list byte, etc, etc.  Thanks!